# Filter javascript object of arrays for all keys

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am new to javascript. lets say I have the following object of arrays

```
const object1 = {
  name: ['David', 'Juan', 'Simon', 'Lukas'],
  age: [41, 22, 33, 50],
  salary: [100, 80, 120, 150]
};
```

I would like to create a new object which filter the data of people older than a value (e.g. 30). I was loooking to filter, Object.fromEntries, Object.entries but I couldnt find a possible solution.
The result should be

```
NewObject {
  name: Array['David', 'Simon', 'Lukas'],
  age: Array[41, 33, 50],
  salary: Array[100, 120, 150]
};
```

Thanks for any suggestions

Comment: Any reason for that data structure? Why not just an array of objects with each object representing 1 person?

Comment: Hi, yes in fact the structure is comming from Bokeh ColumnDataSource. I am using Javascript as part of js callback for plotting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy to understand solution:

```
const maxAge = 30;
const object = {
  name: ['David', 'Juan', 'Simon', 'Lukas'],
  age: [41, 22, 33, 50],
  salary: [100, 80, 120, 150]
};

const result = { name: [], age: [], salary: [] };

for (let i = 0; i < object.name.length; i++) {
    if (object.age[i] <= maxAge) {
        result.name = [...result.name, object.name[i]];
        result.age = [...result.age, object.age[i]];
        result.salary = [...result.salary, object.salary[i]];
    }
}
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks, your solution is easy to understand. It help me to solve the callback.

Answer (score 2):

Convert your current structure to a more convenient data structure(JSON) like this:

```
const workers = [
  {
    name   : 'David',
    age    : 41,
    salary : 100
  },
  {
    name   : 'Juan',
    age    : 22,
    salary : 80
  },
  {
    name   : 'Simon',
    age    : 33,
    salary : 120
  },
  {
    name   : 'Lukas',
    age    : 50,
    salary : 150
  }
];

const olderThan30 = workers.filter(worker => worker.age > 30);

console.log(olderThan30);
// This console log will return this, an array of JSON objects that match the criteria of the filter function.
// [
//  { name : "David", age : 41, salary : 100 },
//  { name : "Simon", age : 33, salary : 120 },
//  { name : "Lukas", age : 50, salary : 150 }
// ]
```

I hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks, I dont to change the structure since I need to give it back to a ColumnDataSource object in the same way after filtering

Answer (score 1):

Like @CharlieFish mentioned, your data structure is not the normal way of doing things, which is where you'd do this instead:

```
const employees = [
  { name: 'David', age: 41, salary: 100 },
  { name: 'Simon', age: 33, salary: 120 },
  { name: 'Lukas', age: 50, salary: 150 },
];

const over30 = employees.filter(employee => employee.age > 30);
```

If you did need to stick with your pattern instead, you can still do it, but you'd have to filter each individual array:

```
const isOver30 = (_, i) => object1.age[i] > 30;

const thoseOver30 = {
  name: object1.name.filter(isOver30),
  age: object1.age.filter(isOver30),
  salary: object1.salary.filter(isOver30)
}
```

...or less duplicative:

```
const thoseOver30 = Object
  .entries(object1)
  .map(([prop, array]) => ({ [prop]: array.filter(isOver30) }))
  .reduce((result, props) => Object.assign(result, props), {});
```

Comment: Hi Jacob, I tried you solution and it works. I accepted the answer from Simone since it was easier for me to understand. I will continue to learn js and hopefully I can follow in future implementation as yours. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could create one object where keys are indexes of the elements where `age >= 30` and then use that object as hash table for filtering.

```js
const data = {
  name: ['David', 'Juan', 'Simon', 'Lukas'],
  age: [41, 22, 33, 50],
  salary: [100, 80, 120, 150]
}

const hash = data.age.reduce((r, e, i) => {
  if (e >= 30) r[i] = true;
  return r;
}, {})

for (let i in data) {
  data[i] = data[i].filter((_, j) => hash[j])
}

console.log(data)
```

You could also use different data structure to get an array of objects with `reduce` method and then just apply filter.

```js
const data = {
  name: ['David', 'Juan', 'Simon', 'Lukas'],
  age: [41, 22, 33, 50],
  salary: [100, 80, 120, 150]
}

const result = Object
  .entries(data)
  .reduce((r, [k, v]) => {
    v.forEach((e, i) => {
      if (!r[i]) r[i] = {}
      r[i][k] = e;
    })

    return r;
  }, [])
  .filter(({ age }) => age >= 30)

console.log(result)
```